# CSS Font Images

Tags: html, css

another quick question. I've seen this multiple times now in different code sets. Someone calls for an image from the css

HTML:

```
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-map-marker2"></i></a>
```

CSS

```
.icon-map-marker2:before {
    content: "\e6f9";
}
```

Which gives the output of this:

[image]

As you can see the picture isn't transparent background. I was looking to edit it to give it transparency, but can't seem to find out how. I've also tried things with the CSS like:

```
style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);"
// Changing the last value's number though and stuff like that
opacity: 1;
// etc
```

I want to keep the gold color, but have a transparent background! Thanks for the assistance!

An example is on Canvas' live preview - Hover Home -> One Page: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/full_screen_preview/9228123?_ga=2.252490057.1116575863.1496646725-686174233.1494200798

Comment: do you have a sample online where we can see this? perhaps jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the code works, it's with font-icons or something like that. not entirely sure, trying to figure it out myself :/ It's nto font-awesome which I've used before

Comment: Without a [MCVE] we could be guessing here. If we can't replicate the problem, it is **very** hard to help you.

Comment: @ericosg http://preview.themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/full_screen_preview/9228123?_ga=2.252490057.1116575863.1496646725-686174233.1494200798 here's one place I saw this

Comment: Please provide working example, not just image. It may be that your font icon has background *build-in* or you have higher priority rule that applies background color

Comment: @Justinas Updated thread and comments!

Comment: @JohnBarr Your links does is not minimal example

Comment: I can't find an example anywhere on either of the links you have provided. This is why we like *minimal* examples. The easier your make our lives the quicker and more likely it is we can help you

Comment: Either your a href/link or your <i> has a white background. Icon fonts, by definition, don't have backgrounds.

Comment: Suggested edit: `An example is on Canvas' live preview - Hover Home -> One Page` --> `An example is on Canvas' live preview Hover over menu "Shortcodes->Maps" See icon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding css for `a` tag for background color:

```
a{
  background:transparent;
}
```

Background coming form .fbox-icon this div.. just add css for that

```
.feature-box.fbox-bg.fbox-center .fbox-icon {
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: can you add working demo or link of code so we can help u?

Comment: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/full_screen_preview/9228123?_ga=2.252490057.1116575863.1496646725-686174233.1494200798

This has it at the bottom

Comment: Oh weird the link doesn't change - you have to hover Home -> One Page

Comment: @johnBarr background coming form `.fbox-icon` this div... just add css for this `.fbox-icon{ background:transparent;}`

Comment: That did it, need the !important (or just re-prioritize better). Personal question now what do you think looks better, the two on the left or the two on the right? http://prntscr.com/fg12fa The last is when hovering over. Like the 3rd goes Black to Gold when hovering. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An option... Download the photo and save it as a png with a transparent BG.

Personally I use Photoshop though there is a free software called [Gimp - Free & Open Source Image Editor](https://www.gimp.org/) that will allow you to format transparent photos and then save them as `.png`.

- Typical method involved saving an image locally, editing and
  exporting as transparent png.
- Right click the hosted photo in your browser and then choose `Open Image In New Tab`
- Right click on the image within the newly opened tab and select `Save link as`, then choose your destination folder.
- Open your image editor software, see my link below for GIMP if needed.
- Typically, if you have a good contrast between the BG and the
  image or the background is one solid color, as is in your case. You can pull the image out of the background by using the Magic Wand tool.
- You can also use the `lasso` tool to make the selection, where you sort of draw around the selection. However, this method is a bit more tedious and time consuming.
- Once you have your image selected apart from the background you wish to remove, simply hit the delete button to delete the selected pixels. *MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THE BACKGROUND SELECTED AND NOT THE IMAGE WHEN YOU DELETE!
- **Only need feather if you have soft edges, if not skip feathering.**
- **Feather:** Feather the selection. Under Select->Modify->Feather. Enter a low number like .5 though you may need to experiment to find the right amount
  to feather your softer edges, when needed. Then select the inversion and delete the selected inversion to apply the feather and soften your edge.
- Now export your image as a `.png` file and host it so you can link to the new transparent image.
- In PhotoShop, you would choose `File->Save For Web`  Choose `PNG-24` and select `Transparent`

  - Note the size, preview if needed, then save.
- Now re-host within your websites image file structure or online at    imgur or other img site and link to the newly posted
  transparent pic.